# What is the main purpose of this yellow part after the fuse?

Tags: battery-charging, identification, repair, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

My friend brought a board to me for repair. This board is a solar tracking board. It is powered by a 24 V PV panel. It is supposed to charge a battery. If there is no sun, the battery will supply energy to the board. This board's main function is to send an angle to a motor.

This is the board:

[image]

The problem is that this board can not charge the battery. If I connect 24 VDC directly to the PV socket it works and the LEDs blink, but the battery isn't charged.

The current is not enough so I figured out the which part is decreasing the current. The yellow part is about 560 Ω, so maybe the visual suspect is this part. What is it? It looks like an NTC. I can't find its datasheet. What is the actual value of this part?

[image]

It doesn't draw much current  if I measure the input (about 24 mA), so there is no short circuit or a part heating up.

If I measure the big SMD capacitors and Zener diodes it looks fine. If I measure the battery output at the begining, the voltage increases to 8 V and then decreases immediately to 0.5 V. If I put a load like a DC motor on the battery output, it shows 0 V; very strange behaviour. What should I do? Can you help me?

Schematic and board images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How old is it?  Have you tried charging the battery in any other equipment?  Of all of the parts in your picture, the one most likely to wear out and fail is the battery.

Comment: Well everything is new about 3 months, also i have 3 same board they are working, only this board not charging

Comment: My suggestion would be power up a working board and the faulty one and see where there are any voltage differences.  It's only three months old?  Send it back to the manufacturer!

Comment: 3 months is short, but batteries still may fail. Please try to charge it with an external charger just to rule out a bad battery.

Comment: Could be an inrush current limiter, where a high impedance would be normal--that resistance goes down after current passes through it for a bit. The idea is to avoid a large current surge when first turned on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part is an over voltage protection component,
68V Zinc Oxide Varistor
(MOV) Metal Oxide Varistors or
(VDRs) Voltage-Dependent Resistors

Jiuyin JOYIN Multilayer Varistor JVR05N680K

Data sheet:
https://tvsat.com.pl/PDF/V/VARISTOR_ZINC.pdf

Translated Page:
https://hongmingdz-com.translate.goog/index.php?m=content&c=index&a=show&catid=827&id=6697&_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=zh-CN&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=sc

Comment: If that part measures 560 ohms out of the circuit, it has probably started to fail. An MOV should read at least 100k or so. After absorbing energy from overvoltage spikes, it will gradually have lower resistance.

Comment: Well out of circuit it shows bigger resiztance. I think this part not broken, I am still searching thanks